# Can I accept an unpopular answer that sees the spirit of the original question rather than the technical correctness of the edited one ?

Tags: discussion

Say Answer A is upvoted by most-users. B ranks next at half the no. of upvotes and C at one-third of upvotes as A.

I do like A for its technical validity, historical accuracy and relevance. 
However, the question had been edited quite a bit and I find C seeks to answer the spirit of the question (the reason OP had in mind) as captured in the original question that existed prior to edits.

I want to give the 'Accept' status to C. Because, I think, anyway A has its place of glory by being the most voted and will be noticed. By marking C as the accepted answer, I might get more readers from future audience to read it, to see its relevance to the question(well, as I see it).

So, can I upvote unpopular answer, that is not entirely incorrect and not the best either ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, that accept checkmark is yours to bestow. Same goes for your upvotes.

I would advise against accepting a **negatively** voted answer, as those are liable to get deleted. Worse, some might wonder if you are somehow in cahoots with the person who gave that answer (I see all the flags here, and we have some highly suspicious users. Arguably not a bad thing...)

However, I have myself written (on other stacks) answers that got accepted when alternate answers had a order of magnitude more upvotes. I've also been in the opposite situation. In extreme cases the coveted gold [Populist badge](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist?userid=771) is awarded for having the answer that was "the peoples' choice". Gold Badges are not easy to come by, so perhaps you are even doing that higher-rated answer's user a big favor by accepting a lower-rated answer!

Also, I think there's a certain psychological component to votes. Call me a cynic, but I think the top answer gets more votes sometimes just because its the top answer. The same goes for accepted answers (since they are put on top), so the votes may equalize a bit after you give out that checkmark.

Comment: It can go both ways. I don't DV all that often, but if the selected answer is crap, I might - only because it *is* selected.

Answer (score 9):

You can upvote any answer you like, as discussed in the [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

As for accepting an answer, according to the [guidance](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the help centre, you should:

> "... accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem".

In other words, you choose the answer that *you* think is best - irrespective of how others have voted.

Answer (score -1):

It's your damned question! What did you ask it for if you don't get to say who answered it?